# Need to make class that validates code and generates the outputs shown in comment

Tags: java, class, constructor

What did I do wrong here? Need to print -1 and 100 but I keep getting this error:

**Exception in thread "main" java.lang.Error: Unresolved compilation problem:
No enclosing instance of type Main is accessible. Must qualify the allocation with an enclosing instance of type Main (e.g. x.new A() where x is an instance of Main).
at Main.main(Main.java:3)**

```
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        MyClass a = new MyClass();
        MyClass b = new MyClass(100);
        System.out.println(a.getValue()); // -1
        System.out.println(b.getValue()); // 100
    }
    public class MyClass {
        private int value;
        // Constructors
        public MyClass() {
            value = -1;
        }
        
        public MyClass(int x) {
            value = x;
        }
        
        public int getValue() {
            return value;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is that your main method has no class. Here you have an example:

```
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        MyClass a = new MyClass();
        MyClass b = new MyClass(100);
        System.out.println(a.getValue()); // -1
        System.out.println(b.getValue()); // 100
    }
}
class MyClass {
    private int value;
    // Constructors
    public MyClass() {
        value = -1;
    }
    
    public MyClass(int x) {
        value = x;
    }
    
    public int getValue() {
        return value;
    }
}
```

You can also create some inner classes, as explained here: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/nested.html

But, if you are starting as a programmer, I don't recommend you to create neither inner nor outer classes, and rather create a new class. Something like:

`org.demo.myclasses.Main` ==> This is your `Main` class with your `main` method.

`org.demo.myclasses.MyClass` ==> Another different file for your new class.

Here's another question made by another user with more info about it: [Java inner class and static nested class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70324/java-inner-class-and-static-nested-class)

Comment: Thank you. I forgot to copy and paste the first line from my IDE when posting it here.

Comment: Just a side note, don't use `public` in an inner class. Also, as you can see on the code I posted, the class is **out** of the `Main` class.

Comment: @Alex if your question is resolved, please, close it.